# RequireJS: how to add a prefix to path

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, requirejs, single-page-application

I'm developing a SPA using Knockout.js V3 and RequireJS.

I have ko components written like this:

```
define(['text!settings.html'],
    function( htmlString) {
        'use strict';

       function SettingsViewModel(params) {
           ...
       }
        // Return component definition
        return {
            viewModel: SettingsViewModel,
            template: htmlString
        };
    });
```

Now i want to support localization and for that I have duplicated html for each supported language, so for example:

```
en/settings.html
de/settings.html
se/settings.html
```

I would like to let the user change a language and refresh the app with the new language, is it possible to instruct require text plugin to add the language prefix to all html, so when i write:

```
text!settings.html
```

it will actually load:

```
text!de/settings.html
```

Comment: Have you looked at the i18n plugin? http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#i18n however, this might also be of interest regarding how to reload your content once locale is changed: https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/213

Comment: @PabloRomeo - Thanks, unfortunately it's a big app with i18n and l10n already implemeneted in a certain way (duplicating the html files per language) so i can't change it to work the way requireJS wants it.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well maybe the require.replace plugin (https://github.com/SBoudrias/require.replace) could change the paths that way, and still not break r.js

Comment: That seems promising, i'll definitely take a look

Comment: Unfortunately the replace plugin only supports js and not HTML :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually i went with a different solution, i just added a variable to the path:

```
define(['text!' + globals.bundlePath + 'settings.html']
```

This variable is initialized from session storage (and get's a default if nothing found) and so when a user changes language, i keep it in session storage and refresh the app, and that way the pages are now loaded with the new language.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can let the text plugin prefix the urls. What you might be able to do is create a custom template loader:

```
var templateFromLanguageUrlLoader = {
    loadTemplate: function(name, templateConfig, callback) {
        if (templateConfig.languageUrl) {
            // Language from config or default language
            var lang = templateConfig.lang || 'de';
            var fullUrl = lang + '/' + templateConfig.languageUrl;
            $.get(fullUrl, function(markupString) {
                ko.components.defaultLoader.loadTemplate(name, markupString, callback);
            });
        } else {
            // Unrecognized config format. Let another loader handle it.
            callback(null);
        }
    }
};

// Register it
ko.components.loaders.unshift(templateFromLanguageUrlLoader );
```

Then your component would look something like this:

```
define([],
    function() {
        'use strict';

       function SettingsViewModel(params) {
           ...
       }
        // Return component definition
        return {
            viewModel: SettingsViewModel,
            template: { 
                languageUrl: 'settings.html',
                language: 'nl' // overwrite default
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: That was my first thought, but that means i have to go over a lot of files and change them and also let the team know that from now on we write modules a bit different, I'll try Pablo's first and if it doesn't work i'll go with that approach

Comment: Okay, but I do think you'll have a hard time switching the template as soon as the language changes if you're using the text plugin. If you have a custom template loader, you could also handle the switching of the template inside that loader.